# Attempting AngularJS custom filter that pulls numbers out of block of text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I would like to create is a filter which will pull the numbers out of text that is put in a text box. For example:

User types: The cat went to 4 stores and bought 3 bags of cat litter for 1 dollar.

Result would be: [4, 3, 1]

The filter will see because of a previous filter ['the', 'cat', 'went', 'to', '4' ...]

So what I tried to create was a for loop that would go through the array and check each item to see if it is in fact a number. However, the for loop breaks the app when it isn't commented out. Any help is appreciated.

```
filter('showNum', function() {    
//   this filter is not complete but it will return only numbers from an array
    return function isNumeric(title){
    var numbers, i, len, numberToAdd;
    numbers = [];
    len = title.length;

//      for(i=0; i<len; i+=1){
//          numberToAdd = title[i]; 
//          if(!isNAN(numberToAdd)===False);    {numbers.push(numberToAdd);} 
    return numbers;
      };

  })
```

Comment: Using regular expression is more practical. `"The cat went to 4 stores and bought 3 bags of cat litter for 1 dollar.".match(/\b\d+\b/g)` returns `4,3,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the filter to something [like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hp91dIXbThzvnwzIFbVn?p=preview):

**javascript**

```
.filter('showNum', function() {
  return function(input) {

    if (!input)
    {
      return [];
    }

    return input
      .split(' ')
      .filter(function(item){
        return item && !isNaN(item);
      })
      .map(function(item){
        return parseInt(item);
      })
    
  };
});
```

**html**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input">
    <p>result: {{ input | showNum }}</p>
  </body>
```

---

[image]

### http://plnkr.co/edit/Hp91dIXbThzvnwzIFbVn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

wZVanG is correct, here is a revisit of your function using the regular expression but respecting the signature of the filter so that it returns an int array and takes an array as parameter.

```
 filter('showNum', function() {    
    //this filter returns only numbers from an array
        return function isNumeric(title){
        var numbers, i, len, numberToAdd;
        numbers = [];
        var theString = title.toString();

        var numbersAsStrings = theString.match(/\b\d+\b/g);

       numbersAsString.forEach(function(s){
           numbers.push(parseInt(s));
       });

       return numbers;

 })
```